After extending entity with Auditable i can't remove elements JpaRepository
After extending entity with Auditable i can't remove elements JpaRepository
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@SuperBuilder
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class User extends Auditable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private List<Event> events;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="events")
@SuperBuilder
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Event extends Auditable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}

@SuperBuilder
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Auditable {

    @Version
    private Long version;

    @CreatedBy
    private String creator;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String editor;

    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime creationDateTime;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime updateDateTime;
}

I tried to delete event, it runs, but element is still in database. Without the auditable it is working as it should and deleting event properly. Classes have @Getter, @Setter, @NoArgsConstructor and @AllArgsConstructor
this.repository.deleteById(id);

